# From Multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a large dataset of the basket information with unique invoice numbers in Excel shee. There are 540380 products belonging to over 24000 transactions(baskets). Ex:

- InvoiceNo    Description
- 536365   WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER
- 536365   WHITE METAL LANTERN
- 536365   CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER
- 536365   KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE
- 536365   RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.
- 536365   SET 7 BABUSHKA NESTING BOXES
- 536365   GLASS STAR FROSTED T-LIGHT HOLDER
- 536366   HAND WARMER UNION JACK
- 536366   HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT
- 536367   ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT
- 536367   POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM
- 536367   POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN
- 536367   FELTCRAFT PRINCESS CHARLOTTE DOLL

All of the products are listed in rows. What I simply need is each transactions with same unique IDs to be listed in multiple columns. Ex;

- 536365 - WHITE METAL LANTERN, CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER, etc
- 536367 - POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN, POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM, etc
- 536366 - HAND WARMER UNION JACK, HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT, etc

I have tried to convert this with pivot table. The result I get [is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCjZ1.jpg)

I am trying to have it in this format ; [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTjaP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot Tables have an infinite number of possible configurations.

In this case, add both fields as Rows, then right-click one of the invoice numbers and choose `Field Settings` and on the `Layout` tab choose 
 `Show item labels in tabular form`.

[image: img]

...or choose a different Report Layout in the pivot table's Design menu:

[image: img2]